# How to implement and hide admin zone on the website without login/registration system?

Tags: node.js, web, server, admin

I'm new to web development, and I'm currently making a presentation website(home, services, news, vacancies) for a small company. I'm using Node.js,Express and MongoDB.

The client wants to manage certain content on the website, therefore there needs to be a dashboard, where **only admins** could login/register. But website design **does not provide any login/registration system for users**.

The question is, where do I put a dashboard and how should I hide it from ordinary users? Should I just use url, like `mysite.com/admin`, which should be typed by the admin, whenever he wants to get to the admin login/dashboard zone(it seems quite unsafe, since everybody on the internet could type that and get to the login form)? Or maybe I should make a separate desktop app for managing website content?

How should I approach this problem, what are the best practices?

Thanks!

Comment: You want a login system. Everything else is nonsense. So go get one. (On a beginner level you should rather go with an existing solution, than roll your own.)

Comment: @CBroe I really want a login system, but designers don't )

Comment: It doesn’t have to be visible anywhere in the front end the normal site visitor sees ... if you protect `mysite.com/admin` with a login, that is enough. If no links/buttons to that area are allowed in the front end ... well then admins have to “remember” this path and enter it manually.

Comment: @CBroe Do you mean like, when loading 'mysite.com/admin', first you see "login to admin zone" and after that "login to admin account"? Or just show "login to admin account" form straight away?

Comment: You’re asking like you never used a login system on a website before yourself in your life ... When they enter that “area” and are not logged in, you show a login form ... and otherwise, you show the content/forms/UI/whateveryouwannacallit ...

Comment: @CBroe I never used a login system indeed... as an admin) I just thought that it has to be more secure than just a simple, easily accessible login form. But if this approach is used in production, I'm okay with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to reinvent the wheel as i think you can first explore CMS systems and check if the tools covers your requirement . Since CMS tools brings in lot of website admin capabilities as out of the box features.
Following links will get you started.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_content_management_system